Gravity Forms User Registration - Automatically add user to group based on Group ID passed by form
I am running BuddyBoss which has a number of Groups set up. I would like to create a registration form which can be used dynamically by each of these groups by using Gravity Forms User Registration with a field which passes the Group ID as a dynamically populated number field.
In principle this is how I think it will work:
My User Registration form also has a number field which I can populate via a parameter /?schoolid=5
I want to then create a function that automatically adds them to the BuddyBoss group with ID 5. I have found the gform_user_registered hook, but I don't know how to bind the field ID which is passed to automatically assign that user to the desired group.
Can anyone help?

Can anyone help with this?
